# Получение скрытых элементов JS

Tags: javascript, css

Есть блок со стилем `display: none;`. При попытке его получить через *js* возникает ошибка. Вопрос, как получить блок?

Comment: Вопросы с просьбами помочь с отладкой («почему этот код не работает?») должны включать желаемое поведение, конкретную проблему или ошибку и минимальный код для её воспроизведения прямо в вопросе. Вопросы без явного описания проблемы бесполезны для остальных посетителей. См. [Как создать минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример.](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Даешь объект `html` и событие в `js`, тогда, может быть поможем =)

Answer (score 2):

Опишите ваше понимание термина "получить".
Если вы пытаетесь обратиться к элементу, например, по `documnet.getElementById('id')`, то он должен быть доступен несмотря на display:none, т.к. в DOM'е он существует и никуда не делся. Если у вас при этом возникает ошибка, значит, она где-то в самом обращении, а стиль тут не при чем.

Comment: а почему не так - let variable_name = querySelector('.class_name');

Comment: да как угодно обращайтесь, хоть по классу, хоть по id, хоть по имени тега или элементу массива чайлдов или как к паренту или как еще в голову взбредет. если элемент есть в DOM, то к нему можно обратиться. стиль display:none на это не влияет.